# Solar angle of Incident calculation confusion!

Tags: angles, solar-radiation

How can I deal with an angle of incidence with greater than 90 degree values if I am calculating solar radiation?

Comment: First of all I am confused with different formula available for  solar angle of incidence calculation. If i follow the book by  John A. Duffie  William A. Beckman, there r 3 formula to calculate solar angle of incidence! I implemented all three, but all of them giving different answer. I don't know where is the problem! Even there are few values that are greater than 90 degrees, I know the reason why they are more than 90 but I dont know  what to do with those values when calculating solar irradiation (beam / diffuse) formula.

Answer (score 1):

It would need to be normalised. divide your non normalised solar radiation value by the Cos of (90°-Local Solar Elevation).

Comment: can you suggest me some tutorial or paper that does this? any reference?

Comment: Try Dewa et Danoedoro, 2017.